# Calculating discrete mean

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, means, numerical-optimization

I am not sure if a distinction "discrete" and "continuous" mean exists, but it's the best way to describe my problem: I have solved a partial differential equation $f(u^{'}(t),u(t),t)=c$ on a domain $\Omega$ numerically in Matlab. $u$ denotes the concentration of a chemical substance and I am interested in calculating the mean concentration over $\Omega$. Mathematically, this would be $$\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}u.$$ Since the solution in Matlab is given as discrete solutions evaluated at each finite element mesh point, I thought to evaluate the mean concentration as follows: 
$$\frac{\text{Sum of discrete solutions u at each mesh point}}{\text{number of mesh points}}$$
Intuitively, this seems like a correct approach, but I am not sure if the integral above can be rewritten discretely like the fraction above. Any ideas, suggestion and criticism would be very helpful, because I am very lost at this point. The answer might be very obvious, but my numerical background is not strong.

Comment: I feel like number of mesh points is off and more likely something like the sum of the areas of the little squares in your discretisation. In 1 dimension it would be a sum divided by the lengths of the sub intervals you partitioned $[a,b]$ into no?

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis thank you for your comment! But does it make sense to have sum of areas in denominator when in the nominator not the integral, but sum of the concentrations are evaluated?